# How to provide stroke and rounded inner corners in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, rounded-corners

I am having  `custom ImageView` which will be having stroke and rounded inner corners.

[image]    [image]

I have successfully been able to do this. But I also want to perform zoom & translate on this image. So if I perform zooming, then rounded corners is not seen.

Below is the code which I have used:

```
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bg_image_bitmap.getWidth(),bg_image_bitmap.getHeight(),bg_image_bitmap.getConfig());

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

final Paint paint = new Paint();
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bg_image_bitmap
        .getWidth(), bg_image_bitmap.getHeight());

final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(
        R.color.theme_red));
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundCornerRadius,
        roundCornerRadius, paint);

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
        Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bg_image_bitmap, rect, rect,
        paint);

paint.setXfermode(null);

view_BG.setImageBitmap(output);
```

I know I have given image height and width to canvas, so issue will arise. But I am not getting other option to proceed.

Please help me to fix this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think while zooming, you have to recalculate the width and height of image and again recall above code.

Comment: I am using that image height,width only. and providing that data to output bitmap. It is giving height and width of entire image (includes non visible area of image too). and due to that reason, second image is like this.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer!